# "Show that, if all the entries of A on or below the diagonal are zero, then A is nilpotent."

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given this question in a problem set. Is it phrased correctly? 
Surely the identity matrix is one which has all entries below the diagonal equaling zero and it cannot be nilpotent.

Comment: the diagonal should be zero. It is said *on or below* the diagonal

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ triangular matrix $A$ are the entries on its main diagonal, which in this case are all zero. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, this means that $A^n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with zeroes on and below the diagonal. Let $T$ be the linear transformation represented by $A$ with respect to the standard basis. Show that $A$ having zeroes on and below the diagonal implies that
$$T(e_i) \in \textrm{Span}\{e_1,\ldots, e_{i-1}\}.$$
Use induction to show that $\textrm{Span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\} \subset \ker(T^k)$ for each $1 \leq k \leq n$. Therefore $T^n$ is the zero transformation, so $A$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a nilpotent matrix then the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$. Indeed if $b$ is an eigenvector for $A$ then $Av=\lambda v$ and $A^m v=\lambda ^m v=0$  and from here $\lambda =0$. On the contrary if $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues equal to $0$ the matrix is nilpotent. Indeed the matrix is similar to an upper triangular with all zero on the principal diagonal($N$). You can demonstrate by induction that exist an an integer $1\le k\le n$ such that $N^k=0$ but if $A=M^{-1}NM$ then $A^k=M^{-1}N^kM=0$